# Did Kaji know that he was going to die in Episode 21?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

In Episode 21 of the Anime, Kaji is (supposedly) killed by an unknown third party in a drainage tunnel somewhere in Tokyo 3. Just before he died, he proclaimed to the shooter that they were late with a smile on face, and a shot is heard when the screen fades to black.

Now, I know that Kaji was a agent working for multiple firms, as well as serving his own interests, primarily working for SEELE and NERV as double agents for each respective organization, which means that he worked in areas like black ops and espionage, "retrieving" information for the parties concerned in secret.

This meant that he uncovered some information that either or both parties were very cautious about, and would ultimately mean that the respective party would go through excessive means to stop the leak.

My question is this, when Kaji stole the information from all parties concerned, did he know before hand that he was going to die very, very soon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He knew that he was going to die but it was not directly due to his espionage.
Freeing the kidnapped Fuyutsuki is the most likely cause of his death according to the dialogue in episode 21.

> Misato:         Hello, I am away right now. Please leave your message
>                   after the beep.
>   Ryouji:        My last job...
>   ...
>   Fuyutsuki:      It's you.
>   Ryouji:         It's been a while.
>   Fuyutsuki:      This action will result in your death.
>   Ryouji:         All I wish is to get closer to the truth...
>                   within me.
>   [Script](http://nge.otaku.ru/scripts/eva21.txt)